# Is $L=\{w_1 c w_2\mid w_1,\ w_2\in\{a,b\}^*,\ w_1≠w_2\}$ context free?

Tags: formal-languages

Is $L=\{w_1 c w_2 \mid w_1,\ w_2\in\{a,b\}^*,\ w_1≠w_2\}$ context free? How?

I am trying to build a pda but do not know how to check the inequality.

Comment: This might help you: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19151/is-the-complement-of-ww-context-free